# Help with setting Winedt 9.1 version

Tags: pdf, compiling, editors

I would like some help in Winedt setup. I use the Winedt 9.1 version and in the others programs like that (Tex center, tex studio), when I compile some file, the program open the pdf file in the page of the sentence that I wrote, but the always Winedt open the pdf file in the first page. Is it possible to set WinEdt to do that?

The second thing is similar, in the others programs, I can open the pdf file and click in some equation or text part and the program open the tex file in the code of equation or text part that I clicked.  Is it possible to set WinEdt to do that?

A possible question : Why I dont change of the program? Cause, I like of WinEdt.

Sorry for the basic english.
Thanks so much.

Comment: What is  your pdf viewer?  Also you should update to version 10.1.

Comment: @Bernard, the Adobe Reader 9.

Comment: @Bernard, I tried to use the version 10.1, but when I went compile the winedt asked to close the pdf every time before the compilation. So I came back to the 9 version.

Comment: Don't use Adobe Reader. It locks the pdf. The best choice is `SumatraPDF`: ultralight (4Mb!), ultra fast, and there is a 64 bit version. With WinEdt 10, you'll find a `Contribution manager` on WinEdt.org, which will make your life easier.